# CQL data type for storing an array of object

Tags: json, cassandra, cql

I need to store an array of objects in a Cassandra DB column, for example, I may have a table that has a column named people, which would hold an array of objects:

```
   [
        {
            name: one,
            age: 1
        },
        {
            name: two,
            age: 2
        }
    ]
```

However, looking at [the docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html?hl=cql%2Cdata%2Ctypes), I can't find anything that would be a good data type for this except for `people set<blob>` but I'm wondering if there is something more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use  [user defined type (UDT)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html#cqlUseUDT)**

Create a UDT Type :

```
CREATE TYPE people (
    name text,
    age int
);
```

Now declare the type of people field :

```
people set<frozen <people>>
```