# How to store array of objects in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, arrayofstring

In cassandra DB I am planning to store an array-of-object. What is the best way to do that. object mapping to Data mapping with model class in java.

```
Class Test{
   @Column(name = "id")
   int id,
   @Column(name = "name")
   String name,
   Address[] address

 class Address{
   String add1,
   String city,
   String state 
  }
}
```

Should I put all(id, name, add1, city, state) in one table by adding columns to same keyspace with add1, city, state also? or add new table for address
Or 
any other options..

I have tried to add `TYPE` But throwing error as: "Error from server: code=2200 `[Invalid query] message="A user type cannot contain non-frozen UDTs`"
From the error and type syntax I have used keyword '`frozen`', but not luck. Altering table also gives similar Error something like : "`mismatched input 'frozen' expecting EOF`"

Also,
What if I have to save column of type `'String[ ]'` As it is not custom type like Address[]. it is of String or text.? Do we need to just add alter statement? if so how it looks like

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your case, first, you need to create a UDT(user defined type) in Cassandra.

```
Create TYPE address(
   add1 text,
   city text,
   state text
);
```

Then create a table including this UDT.

```
Create table Test(
   id int,
   name text,
   address list<frozen<address>>,
   primary key(id)
);
```

If you want to know more about UTD and the usages, visit following links:

- [Using a user-defined type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html)
- [Collection type (List, Set, Map)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html)

**EDIT**:

> Also, What if I have to save column of type 'String[ ]' As it is not custom type like Address[]. it is of String or text.? Do we need to just add alter statement? if so how it looks like

**Answer**: `Alter table test add stringarr list<text>` Check this links to get more idea about cassandra data types: [CQL data types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html)

Comment: is there a possibility to add for existing table instead creating table? Because When I try to create typeit throws exception: "Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="A user type cannot contain non-frozen UDTs""

Comment: Which query get the exception?
yeah, you can add a column to an existing table by doing alter command. `Alter table test add address1 list<frozen<address>> `.

Comment: I updated the question, with the error for both adding type and altering table

Comment: I was doing a mistake over there in query.  Now I am able to alter the table with Custom type. Thanks.

Comment: What if I have to save column of type 'String[ ]' As it is not custom type like Address[]. it is of String or text.? Do we need to just add alter statement? if so how it looks like.

Comment: `Alter table test add stringarr list<frozen<text>>` or `Alter table test add stringarr list<address>` would do.

Answer (score 2):

you can create UDT type:

```
CREATE TYPE people (
    name text,
    address
);
```

and now declare your field like this

```
people set<frozen <people>>
```

I hope it's help you

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222734/cql-data-type-for-storing-an-array-of-object]. instead set can I use array or List?